# Парсинг рекламных компаний HH через API

Tags: python, api

У меня есть API Head Hunter.я авторизовался, но я не понимаю как выгружать рекламные компании и скачивать их в CSV, подскажите пожалуйста есть ли пример кода или хотя бы в каком направлении искать

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Надо начать с того, что поискать информацию о том, как в целом происходит парсинг сайтов. То, что вы не знаете с чего начать и не предоставили ни строчки кода показывает, что вам надо ознакомится с основами. [Тут много хороших примеров, с чего начать](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqGS6O1-DZLprgEaEeKn9BWKZBvzVi_la)

Comment: Вы правы, действительно, мне необходимо ознакомится с основами